# Basic C++ atomic array

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, c++11

I am trying to use a basic array of objects using C++11 atomics, i.e. below:

```
// Atomic array
std::atomic<Object*> *array = new std::atomic<Object*>[10];

// Storing old data
array[0].store(oldObject);

// Store the new data
Object *newObject = new Object();
while(!array[0].compare_exchange_strong(oldObject,newObject));
```

My question is, can the CAS operation fail **only** if another thread is modifying the the array at the same index? Or will the CAS operation fail if any thread is trying to modify **any** location within the array? The latter is the behaviour that I seem to be getting during tests. If so, is there a better way to declare an array so that modifying different individual cells in the array don't effect each other?

Thanks.

Comment: If different atomic objects could randomly influence each other I do not see how you would ever be able to program them.

Comment: Do you need an array (a block of contiguous memory containing adjacent data), or a container that associates indexes with data?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC atomic variables on a single cache-line will share the locking (on x86{,_64}).

So maybe extend the array and try variables at each end to test that?